# How to write javascript on asp.net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to write javascript code  on asp.net page such as (input box) to get value in a better manner  ....
or another controls message boxes (alert,confirm,......
(please if you can, give me an example? )

Comment: the best option is to put all the javascript functions in a separate .js file and while deloying the application minify the .js and use it.

Comment: @Aravind: minifying is sometimes just too overrated... at least you've got the browser cache :) if you'd really like to optimize, you'd better create one big file to minimize the requests!

Comment: @Andreas one cannot generalise it and have to deal with it on a case to case basis.

Comment: @Aravind: neither you can... so throwing "MINIMIZE!" in is as stupid as my suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ClientID` property. Example

```
<img src="images\cal.gif" 
onclick="openCalendar(<% = txtDate.ClientID %>, 150, -150);return false;" />
```

[Soure](http://www.aspdeveloper.net/tiki-index.php?page=ASPFAQFindControl)

Answer (score 1):

as you would on a "normal" html page :)

you can enhance your scripts - no, sometimes you MUST - with eg.

```
<%= this.inputBox.ClientID %>
```

i would recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for such enhancements ... its feature rich, easy to learn, ...

you could do eg.

```
var $inputBox = $('#<%= this.inputBox.ClientID %>');
$inputBox.hide();
var oldValue = $inputBox.val();
$inputBox.val('now it has no value');
```

.. and many more!

there are many tutorials on the net... to give a very rough overview, try [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=231)